# How can I implement server sent events (SSE) in SvelteKit?

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events, sveltekit

I can't find a tutorial for SvelteKit without using custom express server. Are there any alternatives with an API endpoint?

I've tried setting up the API endpoint myself, but I can't make it send an update when the data changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably have to return a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) that you can write the updates to. That way the connection is not closed.

As of now there is [an open issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/5344) regarding more documentation on this.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @Paolo's idea. Here is a more concrete example:

In your `+server.js` file, implement following code:

```js
// SSE only supports GET request
export async function GET({ url }) {
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
            // You can enqueue multiple data asynchronously here.
            const myData = ["abc", "def"]
            myData.forEach(data => {
                controller.enqueue(`data: ${data}\n\n`)
            })
            controller.close() 
        },
        cancel() {
            // cancel your resources here
        }
    });

    return new Response(stream, {
        headers: {
            // Denotes the response as SSE
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream', 
            // Optional. Request the GET request not to be cached.
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
        }
    })
}
```